# Reuseable CustomControl Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, custom-controls

I have a problem with reusable controls, and I nedd your help. The problem looks like this, I have created a custom control:

```
public class ControlExtender : ContentControl
{
    static ControlExtender()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ControlExtender), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ControlExtender)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
    }
}
```

In addition I have a ControlTemplate

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ControlExtender}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    ...content....
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I created an additional class, which contains a handful of AttachedProperties. Among other things, this one:

```
public class Extender
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ControlTemplate", 
        typeof(ControlTemplate), 
        typeof(Extender), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, 
            MetadataOptions, 
            OnControlTemplateChanged, 
            CoerceRadingControlTemplate));

    public static ControlTemplate GetControlTemplate(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ControlTemplate)element.GetValue(ControlTemplateProperty);
    }
    public static void SetControlTemplate(UIElement element, ControlTemplate value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ControlTemplateProperty, value);
    }
```

This Extender class creates a new popup. Content of the popup should be the custom control ControlExtender. In my XAML code I want to implement a statement like this:

```
p: Extender.ControlTemplate = "{?}"
```

But how can I specify the custom control ControlExtender here? Sorry if this question is too trivial, but now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple

since you've defined the target type it also act as the key for the resource

```
p:Extender.ControlTemplate = "{Binding Setters[0].Value, Source={StaticResource {x:Type controls:ControlExtender}}}"
```

this will effectively look for the template if there is some issue like resolving at compile time you could use DynamicResource too

```
p:Extender.ControlTemplate = "{Binding Setters[0].Value, Source={DynamicResource {x:Type controls:ControlExtender}}}"
```

that's all to retrieve the defined template, the trick here is to get the first setter's value which is the control template

Comment: I think i missed something. wait! let me correct it. above example retrieve the style only.

Comment: You're right! By your first solution, I get the message: "System.Windows.Style" is not a valid value for the property "ControlTemplate". I found this solution also, but your correction: "Binding Setter [0]. Value, Source..." is very nicely solved! Thank you so much!